# Group Date on a DTR System Report

Tags: c#, sql

I'm trying to figure this one out, I think the solution to this is just basic but i still couldn't get the SQL Query right.

I'm trying to create a DTR Report and want to group the time in and time out values that has the same date.

I figured GROUP BY is the solution? But the aggregate thingy only includes COUNT, SUM, AVE, etc.

Here's a sample of the output that i want to obtain.

```
Date            Time In          Time Out

07-25-2013       7:00:00 AM      12:00:00 PM
                 1:00:00 PM      5:00:00 PM

07-26-2013       7:30:00 AM      12:30:00 PM  
                 1:30:00 PM      5:30:00 PM
```

I'm doing this project in C#.

Comment: What's a "DTR Report"?

Comment: Should I know what a *DTR Report* is?

Comment: Can you provide your current code?